# Multiple name and value pass through one checkbox or button using css and html

Tags: html, css

I want to pass multiple name and values through one checkbox or one button.
Below is the code which I have tried.

For checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  name="p_rollnum" 
  name="p_classid" 
  value="<%=view.getRollNum() %>" 
  value="<%=view.getClassId() %>"
>
```

For button:

```
<button type="submit" 
  name="p_rollnum" 
  name="p_classid" 
  name="p_name" 
  value="<%=view.getRollNum() %>" 
  value="<%=view.getClassId() %>" 
  value="<%=view.getName() %>">
    Submit
</button>
```

But its not working.So please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't have multiple names or values for one object because it would confuse the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="myForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="p_name" value="<%=view.getName() %>">
<input type="hidden" name="p_rollnum" value="<%=view.getRollNum() %>">
<input type="hidden" name="p_rollnum" value="<%=view.getClassId() %>" >
<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

1. Store the multiple values server-side (e.g. in a database) with some identifier associated with them. Set that identifier as the value of the input.
2. Serialise the data (e.g. to JSON or CSV) and put that as the value

Answer (score 1):

You can't duplicate name attribute or value attribute , it'll take only the first one .

but you can try to use it in another way , and here is three ways to do this

**First way**
you can duplicate the whole input itself and make the name to by like this `p_rollnum[]`
Example :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="p_rollnum[]" value="<%=view.getRollNum() %>">
<input type="hidden" name="p_rollnum[]" value="<%=view.getClassId() %>">
```

**Secound way**
you can pass an object as a single value like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="p_rollnum" value="{rollnum:'<%=view.getRollNum() %>',classid:'<%=view.getClassId() %>'}">
```

**Third way**
to use custom data attribute and pass multiple values on it then get it by javascript on submit 
Example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="p_rollnum" value="<%=view.getRollNum() %>" data-classid="<%=view.getClassId() %>">
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate the first way. So it will become very helpful for me

Comment: if you used the first way you will receive an array with values, the same way if you get values from multi-select input